# Facebook Graph API, POST to {page_id}/photos - reference doc

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Just finishing development of a custom wordpress plugin, for uploading photos with a message to facebook page feed. Even everething works fine, I'm missing some information on official fcb [reference docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/) dealing with `{page_id}/photos` API specification, where "Creating" section says "You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.".

As my plugin is successfuly doing this POST request to `{page_id}/photos`, not sure what given sentence means. Is it or will it be deprecated? Am I violating their policies? Etc.

Code update:

```
if (!$this->pageSession) {
    //Handle missing pageSession (page token is not available)
}

try {
    $request = new FacebookRequest(
          $this->pageSession,
          'POST',
           '/' . FCB_PAGE_ID . '/photos',
           array(
              'source' => new CURLFile($img_location, 'image/jpg'),
              'message' => $message
           )
     );
     $response = $request->execute();
     return $response->getResponse();
 } catch (FacebookRequestException $fex) {
       //Handle error
 }
```

Comment: I think Facebook has currently some inconsistencies with it's docs. I just filed a documentation bug about another issue, maybe you should do the same...

Comment: Could you post here as well the code you're using to upload the photo to this endpoint? If you can, please also let us know the documentation where you based off to make it work.

As Tobi mentioned, can you file a documentation bug here? https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Checked now, the bug was already added as bug [1568904343397127](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1568904343397127/). I will add an answer as soon as this bug will be resolved. What am I hunting for are all the possible attributes you can pass to the request. Thanks for your replies.